# If i use Yum to install a specific version of python, does that overwrite my current python or install an additional version?

Tags: installation, python, yum

I'm trying to install a specific version of python. I will be using yum install python26.
My question is, does that upgrade the current python installed on the machine or does it install the new python in addition to the current one?

I need to be able to keep the current version default (which is 2.4.3) and also install the new 2.6

Answer (score 0):

In answering your question:

> can you install multiple versions of python with yum

Yes you can, but check your OS site first and make sure you install/altinstall, not update and use the different version names, Python2.4 and Python2.6. There is not much info on how to install two Python versions with Yum and a lot of how to without.

[Read mainly the first and last sections, but the whole page is worth a read.](http://illiterat.livejournal.com/7660.html)

[Stack Overflow has some good advice and links, if you prefer different ways to install.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465036/install-python-2-6-in-centos)

Comment: Just to reinforce the "be careful" point... make sure you get it right else any scripts/apps that rely on python (e.g. including system management) may break. Not sure how much of an issue it is with your (unnamed) distribution but some are more susceptible than others.